# Laravel 5.8 Internal server error with ajax

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

i am getting error, Internal server error,

> GET http://isp.local/teachers/168/edit 500 (Internal Server Error)

**Controller:**

```
public function edit($id)
  {
  $teacher = DB::table('teachers')
    ->find($id)
    ->select('*')
    ->first();
return response()->json([
          'status' => 'success',
          'teacher' => $teacher,
      ]);
  }
```

while when i make following changes in controller i am getting correct results, **what is issue in above code?**

**Controller:**

```
 public function edit($id)
      {


$teacher = Teacher::find($id);

    return response()->json([
              'status' => 'success',
              'teacher' => $teacher,
          ]);
      }
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)?  1) [The example they show for `find()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results) shows that you do not use `->first()` with it. 2) [`select()` is for specifying a subset of fields to retrieve](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects), **instead** of retrieving all fields.  So `select(*)` makes no sense (and is not documented anywhere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That query is wrong. `->find()` executes the query, as does `->first()`, and everything is selected by default, so `->select('*')` is unnecessary.

```
$teacher = DB::table('teachers')->find($id);
```

Should be enough. But you're already using the correct

```
$teacher = Teacher::find($id);
```

So there isn't much point to using the `DB::table()` approach.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
 ->whereId($id)
```

or

```
where('id',$id)
```

Comment: Also enable debugger for see the correct error
from env file APP_DEBUG=true

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me what was issue here with server?

Comment: Find retrieves result for a given table, so you can't use get, first, all methods after find.

Comment: From browser network side you will see the response

Comment: it returns blank.

Comment: There is a two request , one Method: OPTIONS which you saw, empty, another one usual header Method: POST